# How to populate a dropdown in rails using a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to populate a dropdown in Rails dynamically using a loop. I want to display the number of days 1 to 30 in the dropdown. I tried this but it printed the `select` box multiple times on my html page.

```
  <%
    for i in 0..30
  %>
      <%= select_tag "time_id", options_for_select([['Last #{i} days', i]]), class: 'form-control' %>
  <%
    end
  %>
```

**Output:**

```
Last #{i} days got displayed 30 times within individual select boxes.
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<select>
    <option name='1'>Last 1 day</option>
    <option name='2'>Last 2 days</option>
    <option name='3'>Last 3 days</option>
    ...
    ...
    <option name='30'>Last 30 days</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this loop within the select statement:

```
(1..30).map { |i| ["Last #{i} #{'day'.pluralize(i)}", i] }
```

So remove the loop outside of the select and change your select to:

```
<%= select_tag "time_id", options_for_select((1..30).map { |i| ["Last #{i} #{'day'.pluralize(i)}", i] }), class: 'form-control' %>
```

The output of the loop will be:

```
[["Last 1 day", 1], ["Last 2 days", 2], ["Last 3 days", 3], etc.]
```

And it should create the options the way you're expecting.

Comment: I like the use of inline conditional, but I would recommend the use of pluralize over it, very useful! http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize

Comment: @user2325154 See here for pluralizing strings. In your case you can do this `"Last #{i} #{ "day".pluralize(i) }"`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/pluralize

Comment: However, one thing I noticed that the value of the dropdown that gets sent to server is not 1, 2, 3... It is in fact 'Last 1 day', Last 2 days' and so on. How can I get that resolved ?

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. A minor change. `<%= select_tag "time_id", options_for_select((1..30).map { |i| ["Last #{i} #{'day'.pluralize(i)}", i] }), class: 'form-control' %>`